# How to multiple matrix column in next columns and set in a new matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to make second matrix from the first matrix in MATLAB. Please see the following image:

AB = A and B

AC = A and C

BC = B and C

[image] ====>>>
[image]

**code**:

```
transactions={{'A','C'};{'A','B'};{'A','B','C'}}; 
items = unique([transactions{:}]); % A,B,C
for i = 1:size(transactions,1)
    T(i,ismember(items,transactions{i,:})) = 1; %convert transactions to matrix
end
. 
.
T1 = zeros(size(transactions,1), nchoosek(length(items),2));
for k=1:5
 for i=1: length(items)
   for j=i+1 : length(items)

      z = bitand(T(k,i),T(k,j)))
           % set z in matrix T1 %                                      
   end
 end
end
```

How to set the new values and How to concate label in the result matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Matlab's `&` operator ([see documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/and.html)). Because Matlab is an interpreted language, it will automatically convert the 0's and 1's to a logical matrix.

For example:

```m
X = [1 0 1; 1 0 0; 1 1 1; 1 0 0; 1 1 0];
Y(:,1) = X(:,1) & X(:,2);
Y(:,2) = X(:,1) & X(:,3);
Y(:,3) = X(:,2) & X(:,3);
```

Matrix `Y` will be of type `logical` and be the desired output:

```
>> Y

Y =

     0     1     0
     0     0     0
     1     1     1
     0     0     0
     1     0     0
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a `struct` for readability:

```m
>> X.A = [1 1 1 1 1];
>> X.B = [0 0 1 0 1];
>> X.C = [1 0 1 0 0];
>> Y.AB = X.A & X.B;
>> Y.AC = X.A & X.C;
>> Y.BC = X.B & X.C;
>> Y

Y = 

    AB: [0 0 1 0 1]
    AC: [1 0 1 0 0]
    BC: [0 0 1 0 0]
```

---

If you want to automate the process, you could do the following:

```m
X.A = [1 1 1 1 1]';
X.B = [0 0 1 0 1]';
X.C = [1 0 1 0 0]';
names = fieldnames(X);
N = length(names);

combos = nchoosek(1:N,2);
for i=1:N
    Y.(char([names(combos(i,1)) names(combos(i,2))])) = ...
        X.(char(names(combos(i,1)))) & X.(char(names(combos(i,2))));
end

struct2table(Y)
```

Which gives the following:

```
ans = 

     AB       AC       BC  
    _____    _____    _____

    false    true     false
    false    false    false
    true     true     true 
    false    false    false
    true     false    false
```

Comment: Thankyou. How to convert my matrix to X.A=[1 1 1 1 1] ?

Comment: @Digipng I can't answer that question without knowing how you load your data. From Excel? From `.mat` files?

Comment: No. i entered data manually. as I show in my code in question.

Comment: @Digipng So then what is your question? I supplied answers for both matrices and structs. If you think my answer sufficiently answers your question, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @ParisaN Please consider accepting/upvoting my answer if you feel it answers your question